# Xcode SpriteKit SKAction not changing properties of an SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift3, skaction

If I create an `SKSpriteNode`, and run an `SKAction` on the node, the action runs on the simulator, but the properties of the node have not changed.
E.g. in the following example, in the simulator, the node starts at (50,50) and moves to (0,0) over 1 second. However, the print statement at the end prints (50,50) instead of the new position (0,0)

```
let test = SKSpriteNode()

test.position = CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 50.0)
test.size = CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
test.color = UIColor.black
addChild(test)

test.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), duration: 1.0))
print("(\(test.position.x), \(test.position.y))")
```

The only reason I can think of is that the print statement executes before the `SKAction` is executed. If this is the case, then how do I execute code later on that relies on getting the position values of the `SKSpriteNode`?

Comment: You don't need to add more `SKAction`'s to print the position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial position of your node is printed before it´s moved to the desired position, what you need to do is print the position of your node when it gets to your desired position.

you can fix it with a sequence like the following:

```
let test = SKSpriteNode()
test.position = CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 50.0)
test.size = CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
test.color = UIColor.red
addChild(test)

let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), duration: 1.0)
let printAction = SKAction.run {
  print("(\(test.position.x), \(test.position.y))")
}
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveAction, printAction])

test.run(sequence)
```

It´s already tested, Hope it helps

Good Luck!!  :]

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Awesome!, glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

In SpriteKit, `SKAction` class have many instance methods, but **you don't need to add more code** like a `SKAction.sequence` and another `SKAction` to print your position.

In fact you have `run(_:completion)` , you can find the official docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483103-run) that

> have a completion block called when the action completes

So your code is completed as is, just  add completion syntax like this example:

```
test.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), duration: 1.0), completion:{ 
   print("(\(test.position.x), \(test.position.y))")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> The only reason I can think of is that the print statement executes before the SKAction is executed.

You are exactly right!

> then how do I execute code later on that relies on getting the position values of the SKSpriteNode?

By combining `SKAction.sequence` and `SKAction.run` method calls.

The `sequence` method returns an action that consists of a bunch of actions which are run one after another.

The `run` method returns an action that when run, executes the block of code that you pass in as the parameter.

You want to print the position after the "move" finishes, so create an action like this:

```
let runCodeAction = SKAction.run { 
    print("(\(test.position.x), \(test.position.y))") 
}
```

Then, create a sequence of action using `sequence`:

```
let sequence = SKAction.sequence(
    [SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), duration: 1.0), runCodeAction])
```

Now run this sequence:

```
test.run(sequence)
```